# Drupal/Civi Groups and Memberships

Tags: drupal, civimember, user-account, civigroup

I've just taken over a Drupal 7 site running Civi. I'm very Drupal literate but new to Civi. Since moving the site to a new host everything appears to work but users' groups and memberships don't appear to be showing in Drupal. I can browse a user in Civi and see they are an active member and belong to certain groups but in Drupal under the user account it says no active memberships/doesn't belong to any groups. This is only since moving the site. As I'm new to Civi I don't know where to start.

Can anyone advise where I should look for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you cleared cache's on the Drupal site and Cleared Caches on the Civi backend? Also under Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration (/civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1), there is an array of database tables. Make sure that is copied to settings.php in order for Drupal to map to CiviCRM if you have two databases (one for Drupal and one for Civi).

Answer (score 0):

> under the user account it says no active memberships/doesn't belong to any groups

This would not show in a vanilla set it, therefore it would mean either that a View is being used to add civicontact-based Views blocks showing on the user page, or that some custom module is at work. If this 'was' working and now isn't, then in the case of the former (ie Drupal Views) then

a/ are civi and drupal tables in same DB or not

b/ if not, have the civi tables been added to the settings.php file so Drupal Views knows where to find them